# Remove partial column duplicates from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I export only 1st column partial duplicate lines? For example in.txt contains lines:

```
red,color,color
red,color,color
blue,color,color
blue,color,color
```

Desired outcome:

```
red,color,color
blue,color,color
```

```
with open(infile,'r', encoding="cp437",errors="ignore") as in_file, open(outfile,'w', encoding="cp437",errors="ignore") as out_file:

    seen = set()

    for line in in_file:

        if line.split(',')[0] == (str(x).split(',')[0] for x in seen):
            continue

        seen.add(line)
        out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: The easiest way is use pandas and the drop_duplicates method

Answer (score 1):

`(str(x).split(',')[0] for x in seen)` is a generator expression, it won't be equal to any string, like `line.split(',')[0]`.

If you want to check if a string is equal to *any* string in an iterable, you could use `any`:

```
if any(line.split(',')[0] == str(x).split(',')[0] for x in seen):
```

or collect the results of the generator expression in a list and use the `in` operator for membership test:

```
if line.split(',')[0] in [str(x).split(',')[0] for x in seen]:
```

But: why don't you just only store the first part of the line (`line.split(',')[0]`) in the `seen` list, instead of the whole line, and better yet, use a set instead, this will greatly simplify your code:

```
seen = set()

for line in in_file:
    first_part = line.split(',')[0]
    if first_part in seen:
        continue

    seen.add(first_part)
    out_file.write(line)
```